# Angle between lines in 3D space

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

If direction cosines of two lines satisfy the equations $$l+m+n=0$$and $$amn+bnl+clm=0$$then show that the angle between them is $$\frac{\pi}{3}$$ if $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=0$$

**My Attempt**

Eliminating $l$ from the two equations I managed to obtain the quadratic equation
$c\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^2+(b+c-a)\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)+b=0$
If $l_{1},m_{1},n_{1}$ and $l_{2},m_{2},n_{2}$ be the two lines then $\frac{m_{1}}{n_{1}}$ and  $\frac{m_{2}}{n_{2}}$ will be the two roots of the quadratic.Hence
 $\frac{m_{1}m_{2}}{n_{1}n_{2}}=\frac{b}{c}$ or 
$\frac{m_{1}m_{2}}{b}=\frac{n_{1}n_{2}}{c}$. Similarly by symmetry one can say that $\frac{l_{1}l_{2}}{a}=\frac{m_{1}m_{2}}{b}=\frac{n_{1}n_{2}}{c}=k$

Now  $\cos \theta=\frac{1}{2}=l_{1}l_{2}+m_{1}m_{2}+n_{1}n_{2}=k(a+b+c)$

So,$k=\frac{1}{2(a+b+c)}$

How to proceed from here