# Angle between two lines is $π/3$ where direction cosines are given

Tags: 3d

I have the following question before me:
Let $l$, $m$ &$n$ be the direction cosines of two lines given by equations
$l+m+n=0$.
$fmn+gln+hlm=0$. I have to prove that for the angle between the two lines to be $π/3$, the following condition is satisfied:
$1/f +1/g +1/h=0$.

I substituted the value of $l$ as $l=-(m+n)$ in the second equation and got a quadratic equation in $m/n$ by dividing the resulting equation by $n^2$.
Let $l_1$ , $m_1$ and $n_1$ be the direction cosines of first line and $l_2$, $m_2$ and $n_2$ be those of second line.

From the quadratic equation, I get $m_1 m_2/n_1 n_2= g/h$.
From symmetry of the equations, I can write $m_1 m_2/l_1 l_2= g/f$.
Also we can write the angle condition as :
$l_1 l_2+ m_1 m_2+ n_1 n_2= cos(π/3)=1/2$.

But I do not know how to proceed from here to arrive at the required condition. Please suggest.

Comment: https://doubtnut.com/question-answer/show-that-the-angle-between-the-straight-lines-whose-direction-cosines-are-given-by-the-equation-l-m-8496098

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880599/angle-between-lines-in-3d-space